# How can I pass a parent's state to be used within a child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, frontend, react-props

I have a parent component where I am looping through an array and setting the state for `clicked` to that of the id of the clicked item in the array.

I am using this component elsewhere where I need to access this state.
How can I go about passing this state down?

Here is my loop:

```
{
 filteredArray.map(link => {
  return (
   <div
   key={link.id}
   role="button"
   style={{paddingBottom: 20}}
   onClick={this.changeView(link.id)}
   onKeyPress={() => {}}
   tabIndex={0}
  >
  <Paragraph size="large">
    <a className='heading__dropdown__link'>
     {link.label}
    </a>
  </Paragraph>
 </div>
)
})
}
```

Here is my function where I am setting the state for `clicked`

```
  changeView(id) {
    return (
      () => this.setState({clicked: id})
    )
  }
```

And here is where I am using the above component:
How can I use the above state here?

```
 <HeadingDropdown
  expandedTitle="Change view"
  links={links}
  heading={currentLocation}
 />
```

Comment: Is HeadingDropdown defined anywhere inside your Parent component?

Comment: I have the same question as @ChristopherNgo asked. Also, your `onClick` does not work as it is. It should be like that: `onClick={() => this.changeView(link.id)}` Oh sorry, you are currying your handler function. Forget about my comment.

Comment: @ChristopherNgo HeadingDropdown is the component where I'm looping through the array. I'm then importing HeadingDropdown somewhere else. I want to be able to access HeadingDropdown's states where ever I'm importing HeadingDropdown to.

Comment: This seems anti-pattern. Generally state flows top to down but you want to access a child's state from the parent right? You should probably change your logic. Either you will use a container component and lift the state up, then reach this state in other children or use someting like Redux.

Comment: @devserkan okay, I changed it so that the component where I am using <HeadingDropdown> is stateful. I have passed down a function to to be used as a prop for <HeadingDropdown>. So everytime the user clicks on an item, this function prop is triggered. How can I use this function to identify which item in the list has been clicked on?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you can do it like you do in `HeadingDropdown`. The only difference will be the place where you keep this clicked item. So, you will use a function in the children, it will update the parent's state. `clicked` item will be kept in the parent.

Comment: Just wrote you an example of how to accomplish this. Let me know if you have any questions. Also thanks to @devserkan for explaining the anti-pattern.

Comment: @devserkan what do you mean container component?

Comment: In your case it is the parent component. You can check @ChristopherNgo's answer. But, for instance if you need this state in another child you can use this parent as a container and pass the state to the children. Container component keeps only the state, children use it and render the stuff. So, this container behaves as a common ancestor for all the children.

Comment: @OzgeCokyasar did you have any questions on how to set this up? I'm happy to help you out if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working off your last comment. If you passed down a function to be used as a prop in HeadingDropdown, you can use it to pass back up it's state-value to the Parent.

Function defined in Parent

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
   state = {
     headingDropdownvalues: {}
   }

   getHeadingDropdownState = (valueFromChild) => {
      this.setState({
         headingDropdownvalues: valueFromChild
      })

   }

   render(){
      <HeadingDropdown passupstate={this.getHeadingDropdownState}/>
   }
}
```

So now your parent component is set-up to consume the state-value from HeadingDropdown.

Now we need to configure HeadingDropdown to actually pass up that value after clicking.

In HeadingComponent, we just need to update your changeView method to call the prop we passed down, after the state has been set. We do this by utilizing the 2nd argument of `this.setState()` which is a call-back.

```
changeView(id) {
    return (
      () => this.setState({
        clicked: id
      }, () => this.props.passupstate(this.state)) //right here you can pass in whatever you want
    )
  }
```

Also here is a sandbox for you to see how it works: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-thompson-ldg3n

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You're very welcome @OzgeCokyasar! I'm glad that was helpful to you :)